# How to Load Custom Listview with a List from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I have created the Adapter class which extends the BaseAdapter and i also the class to query the DB. Now i am stock at connecting both result and the custom layout i Just don't know how to achieve it. If anybody could kindly help

**Adapter Class**

```
public class DrugAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private static LayoutInflater lf = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


    public DrugAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d){
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        lf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = lf.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_title); // title
        TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_description); // description

        HashMap<String, String> drug = new HashMap<String, String>();
        drug = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in list view
        //title.setText());
        //description.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));

        return vi;
    }

}
```

the method in the **DBHandler Class** that returns the Result as a list from the DB

```
//Get all drugs from the DB
public List<Drug> getAllDrugs(){
    List<Drug> drugList = new ArrayList<Drug>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DRUGS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Drug drug = new Drug();
            drug.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            drug.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            drug.setDesc(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            drugList.add(drug);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return drugList;
}
```

Drug Object Class

```
public class Drug {
    int id;
    String name;
    String descri;

    public Drug(int id, String name, String desc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        descri = desc;
    }

    public Drug(String name, String desc){
        this.name = name;
        descri = desc;
    }

    public Drug() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.name;
    }

    public String get_desc() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return descri;
    }

    public void setID(int newId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.id = newId;    
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public void setDesc(String newDesc) {
        descri = newDesc;
    }

}
```

Please any idea how i am suppose to set the ListView Adapter..

i Have tried some few tricks like this

```
List k =db.getAllDrugs();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, k);
    ls.setAdapter(adap);
```

just show that the data is being read from the table.. that's where i get stuck

Code for the getView Method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = lf.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_title); // title
    TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_description); // description
    TextView id = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_id);

    Drug drug = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in list view
    title.setText(drug.getName());
    description.setText(drug.get_desc());
    id.setText("h");

    return vi;
}
```

The last setText is flagging the error..

Comment: you should post the stacktrace

Comment: Sounds like a job for [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Comment: @Raghunandan what stack Trace

Comment: @1baga **but they keep crashing the app**. A crash right. Look at the logcat and post the exception part here

Comment: @Raghunandan not crash per say..this was what i did to try and see if it is working 

`List k =db.getAllDrugs();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, k);
        ls.setAdapter(adap);`

Comment: @1baga so what is the problem? cursor adapter is probably a better choice

Comment: look at my question..just edited it @Raghunandan

Comment: @1baga you can pass the list to the constructor of adapter class then use the same there. in getView based on the position get the list item and set data to views appropriately. Consider looking @ cursoradapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56896/discussion-between-1baga-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by replacing `List k =db.getAllDrugs();` by `List<Drug> k =db.getAllDrugs();`

Then, your compiler will complain about your adapter being a String adapter. At this point replace

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, k);
```

with

```
 DrugAdapter adap = new DrugAdapter(this, k);
```

Compiler will now complain that your list is not the right type. Change references to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data` in `DrugAdapter` with `List<Drug> data`.

Then properly implement `getItem` :

```
public Drug getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

In `getView` declare `drug` like so:

```
Drug drug = data.get(position);
```

Then do whatever you have to do to put the content of `drug` in the view.

Comment: @njzk2 sorry to disturb..i have been tackling this error to the best of my knowledge..everything was working quite alright but when i added a new view to the custom layout and tried to put the content of drug to the new view..it keeps crashing the app but whenever i remove it and put a random text it works...

`// Setting all values in list view
        title.setText(drug.getName());
        description.setText(drug.get_desc());
        id.setText("h");`

Comment: @1baga : you'd have to post a new question about that, comments in not the place for such debugging (would it only be because it is not really convenient and there is not much space or formatting capabilities.)

Comment: @1baga: this issue is different from the original question. please post a separate question. and when you do, post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

It's not usually necessary for your custom adapter to inherit from `BaseAdapter`. There are many Adapter implementations in the framework that take care of a bunch of boilerplate. In your case, you should be using a CursorAdapter for performance reasons. Cursors are optimized for the platform and dumping them to arrays is wasteful for any non-tiny result.

```
public class DrugAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public DrugAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // This allows us to get proper Drug objects from the adapter
        Drug drug = new Drug();
        drug.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        drug.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        drug.setDesc(cursor.getString(2));
        return drug;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // We only need to create the new view here
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // This is where we populate the list item data
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_title)).setText(cursor.getString(1));
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_description)).setText(cursor.getString(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: if i am to use this class you provided then what are the parameters i am suppose to pass to the Object when i am using it in the Mainactivity class?

Comment: The `Context` should be the current `Activity` while the `Cursor` should be null when you first create the adapter. After your query completes (and it should be performed off the main thread), call `swapCursor()` on the adapter, then close the old `Cursor` (if it's not null). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)

Comment: Just curious.. so how is this class suppose to know what list to deal with..cos as it is..it is not receiving any data to work with...

Comment: You're still responsible for performing the database query (just like in your `getAllDrugs()` method), but don't dump it to a list, just pass the raw Cursor to the adapter via `swapCursor()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should study a bit more of `ArrayList`, you are missing something very simple.

You must set an adapter for your `ListView`, like this:

```
myListView.setAdapter(new DrugAdapter(getActivity(), getAllDrugs()));
```

Also, the second argument on your DrugAdapter class is wrong, if your `getAllDrugs()` returns `List<Drug>` object, your DrugAdapter constructor must be as the following:

```
public DrugAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Drug> drugList);
```

Your `DrugAdapter` class must be something like this:

```
public class DrugAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater lf = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Drug> dl;


    public DrugAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Drug> drugList){
        activity = a;
        dl = drugList;
        lf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dl.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
            vi = lf.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_title); // title
        TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drug_description); //   description

        title.setText(dl.get(position).getName());

        //use dl.get(position).yourMethodName() to get its value accordingly to your needs

    }
}
```

Remember: this code is not performance enhanced, I didn't enhanced it because it is not what you're asking, try to figure out what you may do to improve its performance later, but first, try to understand about `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the List which contains the data from the database to the Adapter. Then use the data from the list inside your `getView()` method. You can get rid of the HashMap I think.